# WPF Binding UdateSourceTrigger=Explicit not working

Tags: wpf

I have a Label in MainWindow.

```
<Label Name="StatusLabel" Content="{Binding Source={x:Static core:Supervisor.Mode}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
```

In the code behind is the method

```
public void UpdateStatus()
    {
      BindingExpression binding = StatusLabel.GetBindingExpression(Label.ContentProperty);
      binding.UpdateTarget();
    }
```

In Supervisor is the property where i want to bind to

```
public static DebugMode Mode
    {
      get
      {
        return mode;
      }
      set
      {
        mode = value;
      }
```

Initially the label shows the correct string.
I checked that UpdateStatus() gets called.

My Problem is that when UpdateStatus() is called, the label doesn't update.
What did i do wrong?

Comment: Your problem related with updating a **target**, so why did you focus on `UpdateSourceTrigger` in your question?. That property affects updating of a **source**, you need to remove it from your binding since it doesn't make any sense in your case.

Comment: So I need to define a Path instead of a Source?

Comment: Yes, use `Path` property. Your binding will be `{Binding Path=(core:Supervisor.Mode)}`.

Comment: Thanks that works!